# Is "Her hair is in a pigtail" (singular) used in British English?

Tags: word-usage, british-english, singular

[image: two girls showing off hairstyles; one plait (braid), the other in two pigtails (braids)]

The British say "*Her hair **is in a plait***" (picture 1) but "*Her hair **is in pigtails***" (picture 2).

Americans say "*Her hair **is in a braid***" (No.1) and "*Her hair **is in braids***" (No.2).

I love the word "**pigtail**" because it sounds very cute but I am not sure if it is OK to say "*Her hair is **in a pigtail***" (No.1).

Can we say "*Her hair **is in a pigtail**" instead of "*Her hair **is in a plait**" in British English?

Comment: Yes, I think we can, though reference sources seem to indicate that _pigtail_ is more often used of two plaits.

Comment: @KateBunting So you mean to say, both _pigtail_ and _pigtails_ refer to two plaits?

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh No, I was answering Tom's question 'Can we say _her hair is in a pigtail_?'  We can call a single plait a pigtail, but 'in pigtails' (two plaits) is a more common expression.

Comment: To me a pigtail is braided and contrasts with a ponytail, which is tied at the base and not braided, irrespective of number.  But I am not British.

Comment: That picture is incorrect... "pigtails" is a common term in American English.

Comment: Could you read more widely?

We British generally don't say "Her hair is in a plait" but "Her hair is in pigtails".

'Plaits' or 'pigtails' are personal preferences, not to do with dialect.

We British tend to compare "Her hair is in a plait" to "Her hair is in plaits". Does that not work for you?

We British often accept - and use -  "Her hair is in a pigtail/pigtails".

Answer (score 1):

English person here:

1 'braid' = a plait (British English)

2 'braids' = plaits / pigtails (British English)

1 non-braided hair tied up = ponytail (British English)

2 ponytails = bunches / pigtails (British English)

No, we don't call one plait a pigtail, it isn't used as a singular.

Also, I live near London and have never used the word pigtail(s) and never heard it used except on TV. I would always use the words ponytail, plait, plaits, and bunches.

Answer (score 0):

All the terms you mention are in use in British and American English, but the way they are used is a little different.

In British English, a "plait" is the braiding seen in your photographs. A single "plait" would be one at the back of the head, and "plaits" would normally be two, but could be any number. We do say "braids", but this tends to describe styles with many braids, similar to dreadlocks.

Without the braiding, we tend to use the term "ponytail" to describe a single bunch of hair at the back of the head. "Pigtails" (plural) is sometimes used to describe two as in your second picture, but these may also be called "bunches".

Comment: I would only have used _bunches_ for unbraided in contrast to _pigtails_.

Comment: I suspect we use _pigtail_ in the singular to refer to one worn by a man like the _coleta_ traditionally worn by Spanish bullfighters.

Comment: In New England, at least, a *ponytail* is gathered high on the back of the head, like a horse’s tail, and a *george washington* is gathered at the nape of the neck, as one sees in paintings from the late 18th century. Neither require the hair to be braided/plaited.